# Very slow smtp.gmail.com connection (digital ocean)

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, digital-ocean

I am trying to figure out why my Gmail PHPMailer sends are soooo slow (more than a minute for a tiny email). I tried the following:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

...I get a message saying that the server is (I added the etc's)

```
Trying 2607:f8b0:etc:etc::6c..."
```

Then, 4 minutes later, this output appeared:

```
Trying 64.233.etc.etc
Connected to smtp.gmail.com
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com etc..
```

I am using Digital Ocean and believe that I have everything configured to send mail. I do receive the emails, but not for several minutes.

Can anyone shed some light on this situation?  Could this be why PHPMailer is so slow? Thanks!

Comment: you're trying to connect via an IPv6 address, which eventually times out, then falls back to IPv4. Check if your network links actually support IPv6 for 'external' stuff. If not, then turn off ipv6 entirely.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think Digital Ocean does support IPv6, but I don't know how to check. I know that my droplet has an IPv6 address, but not sure about external stuff.

Comment: @garson Unfortunately, DigitalOcean currently does not support SMTP over IPv6. Those ports are filtered.

Comment: I had the same problem in an AWS environment, because I didn't have an outbound rule for IPv6. :) :)  Anything that blocks ipv6 traffic could cause this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Disable ipv6 in your droplet.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-disable-ubuntu-14-04-ipv6